# UITextView font size not updated

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UIViewController` which contains some buttons: two of them are used to zoom the text contained in the `UITextView`. `defaultFontSize` is initialized on `viewDidLoad()`

Those buttons have a `IBAction` linked to them...

```
- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender {
    if(defaultFontSize < 60) {
        defaultFontSize = defaultFontSize + 2;
        [theContent setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:defaultFontSize]];
    }
}

/* ... */

- (IBAction)zoomOut:(id)sender {
    if(defaultFontSize > 14) {
        defaultFontSize = defaultFontSize - 2;
        [theContent setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:defaultFontSize]];            
    }
}
```

When I first show the `UIViewController` and tap the `zoomIn` or `zoomOut` buttons the text size in `theContent` is not changing.

To be more precise: the methods are called (I've put some logs), but the `UITextView` font size is not updated.

BTW it's changing if I tap other buttons (the buttond tapped are changing screen opacity, so I think that this forces a screen refresh) taking all the taps I made before (i.e. if I tapped zoomIn 2 times I got a +4 in font size) and then start works normally.

**Questions:**
How can I (if possible) force whenever I want a "refresh" of the `UITextView`?
Why my buttons are not working when I start showing the `UIViewController`, but then they work after a "screen refresh"?

I will be glad if you can help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stupid solutions did the trick... I saved the content in a temporary var and reinserted it... 
Not so proud of it, but it's working....

```
- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender {

    if(defaultFontSize < 60) {
        NSString *tmpString;
        tmpString = theContent.text;
        defaultFontSize = defaultFontSize + 2.0;
        [theContent setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:defaultFontSize]];
        [theContent setText:@""];
        [theContent setText:tmpString];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call setNeedsLayout on the UITextView right after you change the font size. Certain methods must be invalidating the layout (like changing the opacity) which makes a lot of sense. Changing the font characteristics isn't going to invalidate the layout - you have to tell the OS that is needs to be laid out again.

```
- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender {
    if(defaultFontSize < 60) {
        defaultFontSize = defaultFontSize + 2;
        [theContent setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:defaultFontSize]];
        [theContent setNeedsLayout];
    }
}

- (IBAction)zoomOut:(id)sender {
    if(defaultFontSize > 14) {
        defaultFontSize = defaultFontSize - 2;
        [theContent setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:defaultFontSize]];           
        [theContent setNeedsLayout]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me like that. Did actually hook up your buttons to your actions?

Comment: I posted the project I used to test it with to my GIT - you can download it here: https://github.com/soverby/TextViewFontSizeChange

Comment: Actions are hooked and they are working fine *after* I force a screen "refresh"